# What are the implications of Bremermann's limit for quantum computing?

Tags: speedup

The title says most of it: What are the implications of [Bremermann's limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremermann%27s_limit) for quantum computing?
The Wikipedia page says that the limit applies to any self-contained system, but in the last few lines they also claim that "access to quantum memory enables computational algorithms that require arbitrarily small amount of energy/time per one elementary computation step".

These statements seem contradictory (unless requiring arbitrarily small amount of energy/time also requires the amount of mass going to infinity). So how does the Bremermann's limit actually affect quantum computing?

Answer (score 3):

> What are the implications of Bremermann's limit for quantum computing?

From the Wikipedia page you referenced:

> "A computer with the mass of the entire Earth operating at the Bremermann's limit could perform approximately $10^{75}$ mathematical computations per second.".

Next you say:

> The Wikipedia page says that the limit applies to any self-contained system, but in the last few lines they also claim ... statements seem contradictory.

The whole paragraph is:

> **The limit** has been further analysed in later literature **as the maximum rate at which a system** with energy spread $ \Delta E $ **can evolve into an orthogonal and hence distinguishable state** to another, $ \Delta t = \pi \hbar / 2 \Delta E$. In particular, Margolus and Levitin has shown that a quantum system with average energy $E$ takes **at least** time $ \Delta t = \pi \hbar / 2 E $ to **evolve into an orthogonal state**. However, **it has been shown** that **access to quantum memory** ***enables*** **computational algorithms that require arbitrarily small amount of energy/time** per one elementary computation step.

The paper referenced, "[Computing with a single qubit faster than the computation quantum speed limit](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05550.pdf)", seems to explain it fairly clearly:

> Page 1: "Introduction. **The quantum phase space of a qubit is a sphere (Fig. 1)**. One can discretize this space into any number of states and then apply field pulses to switch between the chosen states in an arbitrary order. In this sense, a qubit comprises the whole universe of choices for computation. For example, a qubit can work as finite automata when different unitary gates act on this qubit depending on arriving digital words. **However, different states of a qubit are generally not distinguishable by measurements**. So, if the final quantum state encodes the result of computation, **we cannot generally extract this information because we cannot distinguish this state by a measurement from other non-orthogonal possibilities reliably**. For such reasons, qubits **are believed to** provide computational advantage over classical memory **only when** they are used to create purely quantum correlations, i.e., entanglement or quantum discord."
>
> ...
>
> "Quantum mechanically, **distinguishable states must be represented by orthogonal vectors that produce definitely different measurement outcomes**. However, **the switching time between two orthogonal quantum states is restricted from** below by a fundamental computation speed limit T = h/(4∆E), where ∆E is characteristic energy of **the control field coupling to the memory** that is needed to update one bit of information. So, **restrictions on strength of control fields automatically restrict the speed of classical computation** that saves information in physically distinguishable states. While the existence of this *computation quantum speed limit* is a mathematically proved fact, I will show an explicit elementary example that demonstrates possibility of solving a computational problem faster than the lowest time bound that is imposed by this limit on classical computation hardware. **Access to the quantum memory makes this possible because it allows information processing using nonorthogonal quantum states.** So, there is **no more direct linear relation** between the minimal time and the number of elementary logic operations required to implement an algorithm **at given energy constraints**.

[image: Qubit's quantum phase space]

> FIG. 1. Up to overall phases that do not influence measurement outcomes, states of a qubit correspond to points on the 2D sphere. This phase space can be discretized to create a register of states (green circles) for computation. However, **only opposite points on this sphere**, such as the poles marked by |0and |1, **are distinguishable by measurements**.

[Note: You *might* barely get by just skimming just the **bold** text, I suggest you read the whole paper for a better understanding.]

Hopefully that is clear, if you have a comment I can make an edit.